# Inheriting and overriding ostream operator in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, operator-overloading, ostream

I've been trying to find an answer to this, but no one seems to have exactly the same problem as I do.

I am working with several derived classes. The ostream operator << for each of these should print out some things common to each, and some things specific to each.  Later on, I would like to further derive from these derived classes, and again the new derived classes need to print out some things that are in the "generations" above them.
For example:

The Base class .h file

```
class Base

{  



 int FirstClassNumber;

//The declaration I'm currently working with, that a friend gave me
//I'm pretty sure my problem lies here.


public:

friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Base &base)
{
    base << os ;

    return os;
}

virtual void operator << (ostream& os) const = 0;

};
```

The Base.cpp file includes these lines:

```
void Base::operator << (ostream& os)
{
  os << FirstClassNumber;
}
```

Then I derive: (FirstDerived.h)

```
class FirstDerived : Public Base

{ 

int SecondClassNumber;

};
```

FirstDerived.cpp:

```
FirstDerived::operator << (ostream& os)
{
  os <<

  "The first Number is:

 //This is the line that isn't working - someone else gave me this syntax

  << Base::operator<< 

  << "The second number is"

  << SecondClassNumber;
}
```

Then I want to derive:

```
class SecondDerived: Public FirstDerived
{ 

int ThirdClassNumber;

};
```

Second.cpp:

```
FirstDerived::operator << (ostream& os)
{
  os <<

 FirstDerived::operator<<

 << "The third number is "

 << ThirdClassNumber;

 }
```

I think the problem is most likely either the declaration in the very start of the program, or the lines like `Base::operator<<`.

Another possibility is that I'm not redeclaring it in the .h file of every inherited class.  Should I be, and if so what syntax should I use?

It was suggested to me to use the `static_cast` method, but my professor (the one who wrote the assignment, and therefore won't give us too much help with it) said that there's a better way to do it.  Any suggestions?

Comment: "I think the problem is most likely..." - what symptoms are you observing? Compilation error? Line, message? Or undesired run-time behaviour? If so what, and what did you expect?

Answer (score 16):

A simple technique for this is:

```
class Base
{  
    int FirstClassNumber;

    public:
        virtual void serialize(ostream& os) const
        {
             os << FirstClassNumber;
        }
};

// Implement the stream operator for the base class.
// All it does is call erialize which is a virtual method that
// will call the most derived version.
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Base &base)
{
    base.serialize(os);

    return os;
}

class FirstDerived:public Base
{  
    int SecondClassNumber;

    public:
        // Override serialize to make it call the base version.
        // Then output any local data.
        virtual void serialize(ostream& os) const
        {
             Base::serialize(os);
             os << SecondClassNumber;
        }
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You cannot implement operator<< for ostreams as a class member - it has to be a free (possibly friend) function. This is because in the expression:

```
os << x;
```

the thing on the left-hand side of the << will not be an instance of your class, which it would have to be if it were a member function.

To call the parent from the child - do a static_cast:

```
ostream & operator << ( ostream & os, const Child & c ) {
      os << static_cast <const Parent &>( c );
      // child stuff here
}
```

which I think is the "best" solution. Alternatively, give your classes a a named function call Print() which takes an ostream as a parameter and use this to implement your operator<<. This will result in much cleaer code.

Comment: so I need to redefine it as 'code'friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Base &base)'/code' in the Base.h amd then again as 'code'friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const FirstDerived &firstderived)'/code', etc?

Comment: then how do I call the parent operator from the child?

Comment: That is exactly what OP is trying to avoid. The `static_cast`.

Comment: while ugly, in this case the virtual `operator<<` member function is there to be invoked by the non-member streaming operator (which is correctly specified).

Answer (score 4):

Aside from what @Neil says, it would probably be better to implement a virtual `DoStream` method, so you don't need the upcasting:

```
class Base{
private:
  virtual void DoStream(ostream& os){
    // general stuff
  }
public:
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Base& b){
    b.DoStream(os);
    return os;
  }
};

class Derived : public Base{
private:
  void DoStream(ostream& os){
    Base::DoStream(os);
    // derived specific stuff
  }
};
```

So you only need to implement the operator once. You could also make the `operator<<` non-friend and the `DoStream` public, but that is probably personal preference.

Comment: @Juraj: Well, you edited it in while I wrote the answer, so I wouldn't know.

Comment: The original code in the question already has a virtual function in the base class akin to doStream, strangely called `operator<<`.

Comment: @Juraj, @Xeo - thank you!  Please let me know if I've got this right - when I actually want to print out an instance of Derived, the line I want will be

std::cout << derived;

and that will call to the Base operator, which in turn calls to the function which is specified for each derived class, and within it uses the Base function.

Comment: @Tony - what do you suggest?  I didn't quite understand your comment to Neil.  I'm really a beginner at this.

Comment: @BIU: well, what Xeo and Martin suggests is basically the same as what you had - with the correction given in my answer - except they avoid using `operator<<` in favour of a nicely named virtual function in the base class. Overall, I think a proper identifier is less cryptic than a operator being used in an atypical way, so Xeo or Martin's answers are an improvement - no significant difference between them (hence a +1 for both from me).

Answer (score 2):

FirstDerived.cpp:

```
FirstDerived::operator << (ostream& os)
{
     os <<    "The first Number is:"
   //This is the line that isn't working - someone else gave me this syntax
    << Base::operator<<
     << "The second number is"
    << SecondClassNumber;
}
```

You need to call the function by putting parenthesis after it, and provide the argument it expects.  It doesn't have a return value so shouldn't be in the set of things being streamed.  Summarily:

```
os << "The first number is: "; // finish streaming statement with ";"
Base::operator<<(os);   // separate statement to call this function...
os << "The second number is " << SecondClassNumber; // start streaming again
```

Comment: Thank you!  I'm going to play around with your suggestion and those of @Juraj, @ Xeo and the other commenters and see what works the best for my program.  All the best:)

Comment: Would it work with istream too?

Comment: @APars I'm not sure what "it" is - presumably you're not stuck using the same code as the person who asked this question.  The proper way to support istreams for a type you've created called `X` is to write a function `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const X& x) { ... };`  Often it's good enough if the body of the function is `return os >> x.member1 >> x.member2 >> x.member3;` (for however-many members).  It gets more complex if e.g. you want strings to read across whitespace, or to handle units specifiers (like GB and MB for gigabyte and megabyte).

Answer (score 0):

To call a method from base class you can use:

```
Base::method(/*parameters*/)
```

But `operator<<` is a free function. The only possibility without static_cast I can see is to define the operator as a template and then explicitly call the specialization like this:

```
template<typename T>
void function(T const &t);

template<>
void function<Base>(Base const &t) {
    // own implementation ...
}

template<>
void function<Derived>(Derived const &t) {
    function<Base>(t);
    // own implementation ...
}
```

This could be done the same way for operator<<, just change the name `function` for `operator<<` and add required parameters.

---

Another possibility is to make a virtual member function:

```
class Base {
    virtual void print(ostream &os) const {
        // print self
    }
};
```

In Derived class this could call the Base print function:

```
class Derived {
    virtual void print(ostream &os) const {
        Base::print(os);
        // print self
    }
};
```

Then it is enough to have `operator<<` only for the `Base` class and it will call appropriate print method polymorphicaly. Note that the `operator<<` is a free function.

```
ostream &operator<< (ostream &os, Base const &b) {
    b.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: Do I need to redeclare operator << in each derived class's header file as well, or only override it in the child?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight modification to Loki's answer.  Instead of having a virtual serialize method, I use a virtual to_string method.  I think this can be reused in more contexts outputing to an ostream, which might be of use.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Base
{
public:
  Base();
  virtual std::string to_string() const;

protected:
  int first_class_number;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base &base);
};

Base::Base()
  : first_class_number(1)
{
}

std::string Base::to_string() const
{
  return "Base: "+std::to_string(first_class_number);
}



class FirstDerived : public Base
{
public:
  FirstDerived();
  std::string to_string() const;

protected:
  int second_class_number;
};

FirstDerived::FirstDerived()
  : second_class_number(2)
{
}

std::string FirstDerived::to_string() const
{
  return "FirstDerived: "+std::to_string(first_class_number)+" "+ std::to_string(second_class_number);
}


std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Base &base)
{
  os << base.to_string();
  return os;
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  std::cout << Base() << std::endl;
  std::cout << FirstDerived() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Produces

```
Base: 1 
FirstDerived: 1 2
```