# abstract class overloading ostream operator

Tags: c++, overloading, virtual, abstract, ostream

I have a basic abstract class Base.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    string m_Name;
public:
    virtual string Name() { return m_Name; }
    virtual string Type() = 0;
    virtual bool isEqual(Base* rhs) = 0 ;
    //virtual ostream& operator<< (ostream& out) const;
};
```

I would like to overload the `operator <<` to display objects that inherit from `Base`.
I cannot use a `void print()` function because these objects that inherit from `Base` also have some objects that can only be displayed by `operator <<`.

How can I overload the `operator <<` ?

Comment: *Why* can you not use a `virtual void print(::std::ostream&)` function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inheriting and overriding ostream operator in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027314/inheriting-and-overriding-ostream-operator-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

A common pattern is to provide a virtual `print` method, and use that in an `ostream&<<` operator:

```
class Base
{
 public:

  void print(std::ostream& o) const { /* do your stuff */ }
  virtual ~Base() {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Base& b)
{
  b.print(o);
  return o;
}
```

The idea is that each derived type implements `print(ostream&)` according to its needs.