# Inheritance and ostream, how to print derived class with pointer to base?

Tags: c++, inheritance, ostream

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{};

class Derived : public Base
{};

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Base& base)
{
    os << "Base";
    return os;
}

ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const Derived& derived)
{
    os << "Derived";
    return os;
}

int main() {
    Base* derived = new Derived();

    cout << *derived;

    delete derived;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints `Base`, while I would like it to print `Derived`. Is there any way for it to work that way without creating any other function (e.g. a `virtual print()` in both classes)?

EDIT: [Inheriting and overriding ostream operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027314/inheriting-and-overriding-ostream-operator-in-c) is not a duplicate because there the OP wants to print the base class along with the derived class. I'm asking about dynamic dispatch with pointers and references.

Comment: As you want dynamic *dispatch*, you have to use `virtual`(as your `print`).

Comment: _"... is  not a duplicate because ..."_  It doesn't matter what the OP wanted there, at least the 3rd answer shows an alternative without a virtual print() function.